# Python SFTP download files older than x and delete networked storage

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'd like to download some files via sftp that are older than say 2 hours.  Then I'd like to delete them from the network site.  I can use the following code for sftp but handling objects on the remote machine is giving me problems.  The code below fails at the 'timestamp = os.stat" line  I believe it is an os module issue?

```
import paramiko, sys, os,time

host = 'ftp address'
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
password = "pass"                   #hard-coded
username = "user"                   #hard-coded
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)


sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
print 'SFTP Client initiated'

remotepath = "/remote folder/"
localpath = '/local folder/' 

for file in sftp.listdir('.'):
    fullpath   = os.path.join('.',file) 
    timestamp  = os.stat(fullpath).st_ctime # get timestamp of file
    createtime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = now -createtime
    if delta.hours > 2:
        sftp.get(file,localpath) 
        sftp.remove(file)

sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit required for getting the timestamp of the file on remote machine and then comparing it to now is below.  Hacked together by a non-programmer (me) but it works.

```
timestamp  = sftp.stat(fullpath).st_atime  # get timestamp of file in epoch seconds
createtime = datetime.datetime.now()
now        = time.mktime(createtime.timetuple())
datetime.timedelta = now - timestamp

if datetime.timedelta> x:
    do something
```

Answer (score 2):

While the self-accepted answer by OP almost works, it's quite inefficient as it involves a roundtrip to the server for each file. While actually the code has all needed data already, it just throws it away by using [`pysftp.Connection.listdir`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir) wrapper, instead of using [`pysftp.Connection.listdir_attr`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir_attr) directly.

```
for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(remotepath):
    timestamp = entry.st_mtime
    createtime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = now - createtime
    if delta.hours > 2:
        filepath = remotepath + '/' + entry.filename
        sftp.get(filepath, os.path.join(localpath, entry.filename)) 
        sftp.remove(filepath)
```

`Connection.listdir` internally retrieves the same data as `Connection.listdir_attr`. They both ultimately call Paramiko [`SFTPClient.listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr). But `Connection.listdir` returns only file names, discarding the all other file attributes. See also [How to fetch sizes of all SFTP files in a directory through Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51298467/850848).

Though note that pysftp seems dead. Consider using Paramiko directly instead. It has pretty much same API, so the above code will work as it is. See also [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).

---

Also, one should not use `os.path.join` on SFTP paths. SFTP uses always forward slashes, while `os.path.join` uses local path syntax, so [on Windows, it would use backslashes and the code will fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848).

And the target path of `pysftp.Connection.get` needs a file name too, not only a path (here the `os.path.join` should be used)