# How to read contents and attributes of files in remote SFTP server using pysftp/Paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am using below code to get list of file objects  in list from two different nodes.
My purpose is to get the file metadata and compare the files later. But using `filelist = mysftp.listdir()`, I am only getting the filenames and unable to fetch something like `file.content` or `file.size`.

For testing purpose I am using only one EC2 node and calling it parallel.

```
import pysftp
import itertools 
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

# Connect/ssh to an instance

file_list = []

def readFileNode(host):
    try:
        cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
        cnopts.hostkeys = None

        mysftp = pysftp.Connection(
            host="3.93.XX.XX",
            username="ubuntu",
            private_key="/Users/test.pem",
            cnopts=cnopts,
        )

        mysftp.cwd("/home/ubuntu/demo")
        filelist = mysftp.listdir()

    except Exception:
        print(e)

    return filelist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(2)
    result = p.map(readFileNode, ['3.93.XX.XX', '3.93.XX.XX'])
    print(result)  

    print(result[0])
    print(result[1])
    fileList1=[]
    fileList2=[]
    fileList1=list[0]
    fileList2=list[1]
    
    for (a, b) in zip(fileList1,fileList2):
       print (a, b)
       #compare two files and also get the file metadata
```

I have files from both the nodes in `result[0]` and `result[1]`.
But, I want to get the file objects so that I can compare them and list down the attributes. i.e. something like `file.size`, compare `file1.content` with `file2.content`. Where `file1` is from node1 and `file2` is from node2.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve file attributes, use [`Connection.listdir_attr`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir_attr) instead of `Connection.listdir`.

To read the contents, use [`Connection.open`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.open).

```
for i in mysftp.listdir_attr(path):
    print i.filename + " " + i.st_mtime + " " + i.st_size
    with mysftp.open(path, 'r', 32768) as f:
        # Here you can use `f` as if it were a local file opened with `os.open`
```

---

*Additionally, do not set the `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security.

For the correct solution, see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.

---

*Though your better [use Paramiko instead of pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).*

*See [How to fetch sizes of all SFTP files in a directory through Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51298467/850848)*.