# Obtaining attributes of files and folders iterated with pysftp Connection.walktree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

I am trying to list files and its modification time recursively under a directory using pysftp. The problem is, it shows file doesn't exist for all files, but not for directories.

Here is my code:

```
class SftpOps:
    def __init__(self):
        config = ConfigManager()
        host = config.getSftpUrl()
        port = config.getSftpPort()
        user = config.getSftpUsername()
        password = config.getSftpPassword()
        self.source = config.getSourceDirRelativePath()

        cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
        cnopts.hostkeys.load('host_key')

        self.sftp = pysftp.Connection(
            host, port=port, username=user, password=password, cnopts=cnopts)

    def downloadSourceDir(self):
        print(self.sftp.listdir())
        self.sftp.walktree(self.source, self.fileModifiedTimeCheck,
                           self.dirModifiedTimeCheck, self.fileModifiedTimeCheck, recurse=True)
        self.sftp.close()

    def fileModifiedTimeCheck(self, filepath):
        filepath = os.path.join(self.source, filepath)
        try:
            for attr in self.sftp.listdir_attr(filepath):
                print(f"{filepath}: {attr.st_atime}")
        except FileNotFoundError as err:
            print(f"No file at: {filepath}, failed with err: {err}")
        except OSError as err:
            print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
        except:
            print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
            raise

    def dirModifiedTimeCheck(self, filepath):
        filepath = os.path.join(self.source, filepath)
        try:
            for attr in self.sftp.listdir_attr(filepath):
                print(f"{filepath}: {attr.st_atime}")
            filepath = "tmp/"+filepath
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"No dir at: {filepath}")
        except OSError as err:
            print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
        except:
            print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
            raise


# class LogOps:
#     def __init__(self):


# class EmailOps:
#     def __init__(self):

print("=========================================")
test_obj = SftpOps()
test_obj.downloadSourceDir()
print("=========================================")
```

When I try this for a directory with the below structure
[image]

It gives the errors as:

```
=========================================
['.DS_Store', 'about-me.html', 'favicon.ico', 'index.html', 'test']
No file at: /Downloads/techtuft/.DS_Store, failed with err: [Errno 2] No such file
No file at: /Downloads/techtuft/about-me.html, failed with err: [Errno 2] No such file
No file at: /Downloads/techtuft/favicon.ico, failed with err: [Errno 2] No such file
No file at: /Downloads/techtuft/index.html, failed with err: [Errno 2] No such file
/Downloads/techtuft/test: 1569165379
No file at: /Downloads/techtuft/test/style.css, failed with err: [Errno 2] No such file
=========================================
```

Please note, how it doesn't show error for the directory "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use [`Connection.listdir_attr`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.listdir_attr) for files.

You should use [`Connection.stat`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.stat).

Though that would be terribly inefficient anyway. You better copy over the implementation of `walktree` function and make it call `Connection.listdir_attr` instead of `Connection.listdir`. That way you obtain timestamps for all files in the directory in a single call to the server, en masse, instead of retrieving them inefficiently file-by-file.

See also [Python SFTP download files older than x and delete networked storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12360530/850848#56288784).

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the method `listdir_attr` displays current entries in a directory but does not handle special entries such as paths containing `.` and `..`. Make reference [here](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr) from the docs. This is why the `test` folder was not included into your error message.

You can however use the `lstat` method to identify files:

```
>>> for i in sftp.listdir():
...     lstatout=str(sftp.lstat(i)).split()[0]
...     if 'd' not in lstatout: #do something
...
```