# Delete files from FTP older than x day in python

Tags: python

I am trying to delete files older than x days using below code from FTP server.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ftplib import FTP
import time
import sys
import os
ftp_user = sys.argv[1]
ftp_pwd = sys.argv[2]
host = sys.argv[3]
def remove_files(days, dir_path):
        ftp = FTP(host)
        ftp.login(ftp_user, ftp_pwd)
        ftp.cwd(dir_path)
        now = time.time()
        for file in ftp.nlst(dir_path):
            print("filename:", file)
            #file_path =os.path.join(dir_path, f)
            if not os.path.isfile(file):
                continue
            if os.stat(file).st_mtime < now - days * 86400:
                ftp.delete(file)
                print("Deleted ", file)
```

I am not getting any error but files are not deleted. I think os module commands are not working in FTP server. Is there any alternative to delete the files from FTP older than x days. Basically I calling this script from ansible to automate the process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python SFTP download files older than x and delete networked storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360530/python-sftp-download-files-older-than-x-and-delete-networked-storage)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `os.path` doesn't work with files over ftp.

You can use `mlsd` in the following manner:

```
ftp.mlsd(facts=["Modify"])
```

It'll return a list of tuples, each looking like:

```
('favicon.ico', {'modify': '20110616024613'})
```

(the first item is the file name, the second is a dictionary with the last modified time).

To get more information about each file - for example, the file's type, use:

```
ftp.mlsd(facts=["Modify", "Type"])
```

This results in data like:

```
('.manifest.full', {'modify': '20200423140048', 'type': 'file'})
('14.04', {'modify': '20140327184332', 'type': 'OS.unix=symlink'})
('.pool', {'modify': '20200423134557', 'type': 'dir'})
```

Comment: is there any way to check isFile or isDir using FTP? if it is file I have to delete otherwise no

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: AttributeError: FTP instance has no attribute ''mlsd''', it seems FTP server not supporting mlsd.

Comment: In that case, you might have to run 'dir' and parse the results. Do you need help with that?

Comment: yes, can u pls help me in that. I am new to python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215408/discussion-between-hmm-and-roy2012).

Comment: Are you certain you created the ftp object and logged in to the server? This error seems to indicate that the ftp object wasn't created properly.